# Hibernate MappingException converting to ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, collections, hibernate-onetomany

I am having a problem refactoring my code to use the JPA ElementCollection instead of the deprecated CollectionOfElements.
I am seeing the following stack trace:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: UserFilter, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(element)]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass.validate(JoinedSubclass.java:63)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1149)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1334)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)

The changed code in UserFilter is below:

```
//@CollectionOfElements
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(name="UserFilter_orgUnits", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="UserFilter_FILTER_ID"))
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", name="element")
private Set<String> orgUnits = new HashSet<String>();
```

I am specifying the join table name and column name for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Can you add the id mapping on the UserFilter entity?  Also it would be helpful to show the table structure of the UserFilter_orgUnits table.  I am guessing that it what is show below but it would be nice to add to the question.   userfilter_orgunits(UserFilter_FILTER_ID INT NOT NULL,element VARCHAR(255))

Comment: It appears as tho I have mis-matched Hibernate jars from incompatible versions. I will try this using the 4.1.9 jars.